# Cannot Compare The Array Value If It is Number or not

Tags: javascript, windows-store-apps

I am trying to create a Windows Store App and I am not able to compare the array element. Thing is I don't want the string to be compared but it is doing so. Below is the code of the comparison :-

```
function sort()
{
var ar = NumList.value;
var flag=0;
var arr = ar.split(",");
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
{
    if (typeof (+arr[i]) === 'number')
        flag = 0;
    else
        flag++;
}
if (flag == 0) {
    InsertionSort();
    QuickSort();
    MergeSort();
    SelectionSort();
    BubbleSort();
}
else
{
    error.showAsync();
}
 }
```

Even if there is a string element in the Array, it is going ahead and still sorting the element. Can anyone help me out here?

Comment: Unary `+` operator converts `arr[i]` to number, always, even if the value is a string (`typeof NaN === "number"`). Hence `flag` will always be `0`.

Comment: @Teemu :- Unfortunately, if I enter string elements, those are getting sorted in Random order as well.

Comment: As expected. Maybe my previous comment is a bit poorly worded. `+("string") === NaN` and `typeof NaN === "number"`.

Comment: I am still not able to understand. Could you please post an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unary `+` operator converts `arr[i]` always to number, even if the value is a string, since a string is converted to `NaN`, and `typeof NaN === "number"`. Hence `flag` will always be `0`.

You can check `NaN` instead:

```
if (!isNaN(+arr[i])) {...}
```